# Getting a system process id executed from PHP script

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm sending an emails queue using PHPMailer and its `send()` method. It is more than 30 messages in queue and sending takes sometime. Is it any way to learn the process id of the executed `send()` method? I want to achieve storing it's id in the pid file.

Answer (score 1):

`send()` is a PHP method, not a process, so it doesn't have a PID. It sounds like you want to disconnect your setup script from the sending process and send asynchronously, which is fine - the easiest way to do that is via cron (stick a list of the emails you want to send in a DB, then have the cron script check for it and send), but you can also write a PHP script that runs as a daemon - look at the `pcntl` extension.